# SHARE saved Google images list from Android

Tags: file-sharing

Using my Android Acer mobile phone, I created and titled a list of Google Images under my Chrome account. How can I share this with others?

Comment: Can you explain what you did and where this list is stored? Did you simply download a bunch of pictures to your phone?

Answer (score 0):

> You can share photos, videos, albums, and movies, with anyone, even if they don't use the Google Photos app.
>
> **Share to your contacts**
>
> - On your Android phone or tablet,  open the Google Photos app
> - Sign in to your Google Account.
> - At the bottom, tap Sharing.
> - At the top, tap Create Create.
> - Choose photos to share, then tap Next.
> - At the top, tap Type a name, phone number, or email.
> - Select people to share with. If you're part of a family on Google with at least 2 other people, select Family group to share with your
>     family members.
> - Tap Done. You can add a title or message, then tap Send.
>
> **Send a link or share to other apps**
>
> - On your Android phone or tablet, open the Google Photos app Photos.
> - Tap the photo, album, or movie to share.
> - Tap Share Share.
> - Select another app to share or send someone a link. You can also enter or select a name, phone number, or email address.

Source: [Google Photos Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6131416?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)